# Error When Threading with std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am new to threading and have absolutely no idea why the following error is happening:

`c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(240): error C2672: 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found`

This is the code where I create the threads:

```
thread t1(testNextPasscode, 1, passcode, test, correct);
thread t2(testNextPasscode, 2, passcode, test, correct);
thread t3(testNextPasscode, 3, passcode, test, correct);
thread t4(testNextPasscode, 4, passcode, test, correct);
t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
t4.join();
```

And here is the function:

```
void testNextPasscode(int inc, string& passcode, string test, bool& correct) { ... }
```

It seems that something is wrong in the thread class, but I seriously doubt it.  What is going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: What are the declarations of the variables you're instantiating the thread with?

Comment: Thank you Sam, the original question's answer worked like a charm!